# Do the Qt database modules support remote databases through a network connection?

Tags: c++, database, qt, networking

I'm profiling some APIs to see which one is suitable for this project.

I want my Qt app to connect to a database over an internet connection. Can Qt do this with the client application alone or do I need to write a server app to sit on the database server and transact the queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perfectly well connect to databases over TCP/IP as long as the database engine supports that (most do!).  See the example in [the docs](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qsqldatabase.html#details), it has a `db.setHostName("acidalia");` to connect to a PostgreSQL database on that host...

Comment: Indeed, but I saw no example with the host name as a network address. I guess I can just place a network address in there then? That simple?

(Just checking on the capabilities before I invest the time on the API)

Comment: Yep, as long as you have the needed driver, also set the port if it's not what the driver considers to be the standard one for that DB, and the like.